# jQuery method to add a TextBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

**UPDATED** 
I am new to jQuery but have been programming for about two years in C#. I wanted to create a jQuery method that would be used several times to add Textboxes. I thought that I create a jQuery function with parameters which I would set from the buttons when they get clicked. Here is my jQuery code, this wont necessarily work as I am a newbie but will definitely give a workflow of what I intended to achieve

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function add(someClass) {

    var count = $("."+someClass).length;

    if (count <= 20) {

        var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('text'));

        newTextBox.appendTo("."+ someClass+":last");

        //$('.approvers:last').append($("<input type='text' value='' />"));
    }
}
```

});

This is how I intend to call the function from a buttons onclick.

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="someId" class="someCssClass" onclick="addText('approvers')" />
```

I am doing this to avoid writing the same code to insert textboxes having different classes. Is this how it can be done? All I want is to add a new TextBox at the same time specifying its class from jquery.

Comment: Not very clear as you what you are after. Could you post the expected output, say 4 text boxes?

Comment: It's not very clear what the parameters are for. Should the ID be the one of the new textbox? If yes, you won't be able to click twice on the button, because you'll have multiple elements with the same ID, which will mess up when you try to use it. Please explain in more details what the function should output.

Comment: What I really want is to add a new TextBox to a class dynamically when a button is clicked, I have updated my code with what I've come up with, however I get an error  **ReferenceError: add is not defined** What am I doing wrong. Check the updated code first.

Comment: blex I have realized that Id need not be there since am not even using it in the method. What I want to achieve with the code is to be able to add a TextBox of a class I'll pass as a parameter then add the Textbox to the end of the list of textboxes of the same class. I have updated my code to reflect this changes.

Comment: What would be the point of this? Your adding textboxes without any name attributes so nothing will post back

Comment: Stephen I have replaed the line that creates the new textboxes with this
** var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('text').setAttribute("class", someClass));  **
but this too doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: @Dennis, I notice you now have 3 related questions about this. You seem to be misunderstanding some basics. If your dynamically creating textboxes that will post back, you need to give them a name attribute. What is it you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Stephen, I have an ASP.NET MVC project I would like to add textboxes to the form at different instances. Would modifying the jquery method like this for I add the name actually set the name.
**
var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('text').attr("class", someClass).attr("name", someName));
**
I have modified the method parameters like this
**    function add(someClass, someName) {......}  ** Then here is how I call the method in the respective onlcick events **      <input type="button" value="+" class="roundButton" onclick="add('TechnicalFeasibility', 'TechnicalFeasibility')" /> **

Comment: @Dennis, To hard to read you code in comments. But since [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909627/asp-net-mvc-how-to-save-liststring-values-to-database) is more recent and seems related, you need to add the model, controllers etc. there - in particular the model and the property that you want to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little off, try this:

```
<input type="button" value="+" id="someId" class="addButton" data-target-class="someClass"/>

<div class="someClass">
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Define a click handler for any input with the class addButton
    $('input.addButton').click(function(){
        // Extract the class that this input button is targeting
        var target_class = $(this).attr('data-target-class');
        // Add a textarea to that target
        $("."+target_class).append("<textarea></textarea>");
    });
});
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1sfz4sda/

Comment: What is the use of the data-target-class attribute?

Comment: My answer was partially a guess based on your initial question and code. In my answer, I presume'd your use case was to add a text box to a specific element or group of elements. The `data-target-class` attribute (which is an arbitrary name I made up) refers to the element(s) you want to add the textbox to. In this case, I've set it to `someClass`, which is the same class as the `div` I have. As you can see in the jsFiddle, clicking the button adds the text box to that specific div. If you had multiple divs with that class, it would add one text box to each.

Answer (score 0):

I tested below code and it works, do not put your function inside document.ready

DEMO : http://liveweave.com/RkHq5o

Here is the javascript

```js
 
       function addText(cssClass) {
        
            var count = $("."+cssClass).length;
       
            if (count <= 20) {
        
                var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('textarea'));
        
                newTextBox.appendTo("."+cssClass);
         
            }
       
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="+" id="someId" class="someCssClass" onclick="addText('approvers')" />
  
 <div class="approvers"></div>
```

Comment: I tried using your code and this how I called the method from the button onclick event 
`<input type="button" value="+" id="addTextBox" class="roundButton" onclick="add('someId', 'checklist')"/>`
I get an error when I debug on the browser after clicking the method, one error says **ReferenceError: add is not defined**, the other says ** TypeError: $(...).createElement is not a function** What should I do?

Comment: I have edited answer , check now...can you show ur webpage where u get error ?

Comment: I have spotted an error in you code, this line of code won't work
** var newTextBox = $(document).createElement('text')); **
Replace with 
** var newTextBox = $(document.createElement('text')); ** then the error saying createElement isn't a function goes away. However I still get an error that my function is not yet defined

Comment: Hey i fixed error and its working fine...run the snippet for demo or use http://liveweave.com/RkHq5o for demo